# Python - Ideal way to for-loop to store values that gonna be send to a function

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

I have been working to create a script where me as a User inputs into a txt file names that I want to compare if its in a function (Which generates 100 random names) and see if there is matched names.

I have created this code:

```
import json, time, sys, os, timeit, random, colorama, requests, traceback, multiprocessing, re
from random import choice
import threading


def get_names():

    name_test = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('randomnames.txt')]
    return name_test

def filter(thread, i):

    text = thread

    positive_keywords = [i]

    has_good = False

    for ch in ['&', '#', '“', '”', '"', '*', '`', '*', '’', '-']:
        if ch in text:
            text = text.replace(ch, "")

    sentences = [text]

    def check_all(sentence, ws):
        return all(re.search(r'\b{}\b'.format(w), sentence) for w in ws)


    for sentence in sentences:
        if any(check_all(sentence, word.split('+')) for word in positive_keywords):
            has_good = True
            break

    if not has_good or i == "":
        sys.exit()

    print('Matched ' + text)

def main():
    old_list = []

    old_names_list = []

    while True:

        new_names_list = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('names.txt')]
        for new_thread in get_names():

            if not new_names_list == old_names_list:
                for i in new_names_list:
                    if not i in old_names_list:
                        threading.Thread(target=filter, args=(new_thread, i)).start()
                        if new_thread not in old_list:
                            old_list.append(new_thread)

            elif new_thread not in old_list:
                threading.Thread(target=filter, args=(new_thread, new_names_list)).start()
                old_list.append(new_thread)

        else:
            randomtime = random.randint(1, 3)
            print('No changes!')
            time.sleep(randomtime)

        old_names_list = new_names_list
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Keyboard - Interrupted' )
        sys.exit()


randomnames.txt

Alejandro  
Tisha  
Eleni  
Milton  
Jeanice  
Billye  
Vicki  
Shelba  
Valorie  
Penelope  
Mellissa  
Ambrose  
Retta  
Milissa  
Charline  
Brittny  
Ehtel  
Hilton  
Hobert  
Lakendra  
Silva  
Lawana  
Sidney  
Janeen  
Audrea  
Orpha  
Peggy  
Kay  
Marvis  
Tia  
Randy  
Cary  
Santana  
Roma  
Mandi  
Tyrone  
Felix  
Maybelle  
Leonia  
Micha  
Idalia  
Aleida  
Elfrieda  
Velia  
Cassondra  
Drucilla  
Oren  
Kristina  
Madison  
Dia  


names.txt

Alejandro
Tisha
Eleni
Dia
Hobert
```

How the code works:

It starts by the main where there is a *old_list* which saves the new_thread value (so it doesn't loop again) and *old_names_list* where I am gonna save the names.txt one by one.

In the while True that is running for ever, We open the file names.txt and then we enter the `for new_thread in get_names():` meaning it will loop through the whole list of *randomnames.txt* where new_thread is gonna be name by name of *randomnames.txt*.

After that we check *if not new_names_txt == old_names_list:* is True. - What this code does is that it looks if the first name in *names.txt* is inside *old_names_list* if not wthen we continue to create e thread that is gonna continue in `filter(thread,i)` and see if it matches. The point here is that one name by the time is supposed to check all names through `get_names():` before continue the next names.txt row.

And here is my mostly problem so I don't think I need to explain the rest. My problem here is that I have etc 50 randomnames.txt names meaning if I search for one name from names.txt and check through `for new_thread in get_names():` that means its gonna create 50 threads to see if there is any matching. Once the first names.txt name is done, it starts the other one. Meaning that it will create new 50 threads and see if there is any matches. and so on until the names.txt is empty.

My question here is - Is there any better ways to example save maybe all the names in a set() or list or whatever is best and then send it to filter() which is going to check all names.txt for each `new_thread` that is running?

What results do I except?

A result I want to have is that when I run the script first time. It checks all names.txt and store them into dict or list and then sends it to filter. Once its done its going to hit the "No changes!" since there is nothing new added. But if you add a new name in names.txt. Its gonna make the if not `new_names_list == old_names_list:` to be true since the list is not the same. So what I want it to do is that it should only check the new name that got added on names.txt to check all new_threads and see if its matching.

Comment: are you trying to check if the file with names was modified ? Why not just check the `modified date` of the file ? When you're sharing the full code it is not productive to explain what it does, a programmer that knows python can read it. What is productive on other hand is explaining what you want the result to be - maybe there is a completely different and much simpler way to do what you want.

Comment: Oh, Because I followed MVC and it says to provide the code so it works when people want to try it out so thats why. I will re-edit an explaination of a results

Comment: no hard feels. see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood well you want to check if any of the names in `names.txt` is in `randomnames.txt`, how about this ?

```
NAME_LIST_FILE_PATH = r'C:\Temp\randomnames.txt'
NAME_INPUT_FILE_PATH = r'C:\Temp\names.txt'

with open(NAME_LIST_FILE_PATH, 'r') as name_list_file:
    name_list = [name for name in name_list_file]

with open(NAME_INPUT_FILE_PATH, 'r') as name_input_file:
    name_input_list = [name for name in name_input_file]

matched_names = []
unmatched_names = []

for name in name_input_list:
    if name in name_list:
        matched_names.append(name)
    else:
        unmatched_names.append(name)

print('Matched names:\n{matched}\nUnmatched names:\n{unmatched}'.format(
    matched=''.join(matched_names),
    unmatched=''.join(unmatched_names)
    ))
```

output:

```
λ python "C:\Temp\so_test.py"
Matched names:
Alejandro
Tisha
Eleni

Unmatched names:
Dia
Hobert
```

edit: no need for so many newlines, they get copied in from the initial `for name in name_*_file`

Comment: Well the problem here is that it will only exceute once. While if you see my code, I have a While True where it checks every 1-3 sec if anything new happend. Meaning if anything gets added to names.txt, It should just search for the new added name in randomnames.txt? If that makes any sence? I added in the post abit what results I expect

Comment: not really a problem, you can wrap my code in a `while True` and it will run indefinitely. I think what you're missing is closing the file that you're reading, in my code that happens automatically in the `with` block